# Laravel 9 - implode() and whereIn

Tags: php, sql, laravel, string

Hello i'm using query builder in my laravel app. I'm trying to use the implode() method from query builder.

```
    $edi_data_mysql = DB::table('orders_grid')
                    ->select('id')
                    ->where('stato_ordine', 1)
                    ->get()
                    ->implode('id', "', '"); 
                    
    
    dump($edi_data_mysql); // returns "2, 3, 5"

   $jde_data = DB::connection('oracle')->table('table')
                   ->select('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4')
                   ->where('col5', DB::raw("TRIM('Y')"))
                   ->whereIn('oracle_id', $edi_data_mysql)
                   ->get();
```

So for example i expect a string composed from : ' 2,3,4... '
I have to use this string in next query where i use the raw query IN ('value', 'value')

I'm trying to wrap those IDs in to single quotes like " '2', '3', '4' " but without results.

I know that i could use later the whereIn() method that accepts an array as second param, but the problem remains always about the ID wrap, because on the db that value is a string.

Which way should i go for?
I need to avoid the loop*

Comment: The database usually doesn't care if the ID is a string or an integer, it does a loose comparison. The only time I've noticed a problem between a string integer and a regular integer, where `1` is not the same as `'1'`, is on enums.

Comment: From where do you get `'id'`? Is any variable passing or from the DB columns?

Comment: @aynber the problem is that i have to work with oracle db with columns and fields that has not been touch for 20y :D

Comment: ***Which way should I go for? I need to avoid the loop*** I don't see solution beyond this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

commonly `whereIn` method accept `array` as a second parameter. but you are passing string. I think this should solve your problem.

```
$edi_data_mysql = DB::table('orders_grid')
                ->select('id')
                ->where('stato_ordine', 1)
                ->pluck('id')
                ->toArray(); 
                

dump($edi_data_mysql); // returns **[2, 3, 5]**

$jde_data = DB::connection('oracle')->table('table')
               ->select('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4')
               ->where('col5', DB::raw("TRIM('Y')"))
               ->whereIn('oracle_id', $edi_data_mysql)
               ->get();
```

By this way you can avoid loop. No matter it is string or integer, it should work for both.

Comment: Yes i know, i've already tried that way with pluck, but it returns an associative array - what i need is ['2','3','4']

Comment: I tried it again today, this is actually working, even if toArray() returns an associative array. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
    $edi_data_mysql = DB::table('orders_grid')
                    ->select('id')
                    ->where('stato_ordine', 1)
                    ->get()
                    ->implode('id', "','"); 

    $data_id = "'" . $edi_data_mysql . "'";

   $jde_data = DB::connection('oracle')->table('table')
                   ->select('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4')
                   ->where('col5', 'Y')
                   ->whereRaw("TRIM(col5) IN ($data_id)")
                   ->get();
```

This is working fine

Comment: I think your `orders_grid` tables id is a integer and next table foreign id `col5` is a string. well that's a point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).